# Android Studio - Usar la información de todos los registros de una tabla (no solo del primer registro)

Tags: android-studio, cursor, base-de-datos

Estoy trabado con algo que no puedo resolver, ya intenté varias cosas.

Tengo una **BD** con una tabla la cual tiene cargada 10 registros. Si yo hago un cursor (`SELECT * FROM tabla`) me trae toda la información pero del primer registro (`id=1`), yo lo que necesito es poder traerme la info de los demás registros (`id=2, id=7,` etc) pero no logro hacerlo.

Esto es lo que se me ocurrió hacer pero **no me funcionó**:

```
@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long id) {
    BaseDeDatos admin = new BaseDeDatos(this);
    SQLiteDatabase db = admin.getWritableDatabase();
    Libros catego = null;
    int cat = 0;
    listaLibros = new ArrayList<>();
    cursor = db.rawQuery("select * from libros" , null);
    while (cursor.moveToNext()){
        catego = new Libros();
        catego.setId(cursor.getString(0));
        listaLibros.add(catego);
        cat = Integer.parseInt(catego.getId());
        }
            String info = (String) adapterView.getItemAtPosition(position);
            if (position == 0) {
                do {
                    Intent terror = new Intent(Terror.this, DatosLibro.class);
                    terror.putExtra("titulo", titulo);
                    terror.putExtra("autor", autor);
                    startActivity(terror);
                }
                while (String.valueOf(cat) == "4");
            }
```

Básicamente lo que hago ahí es, crear un cursor que recorra toda la tabla y me traiga el id (`getString(0)`).

Entonces abajo hago un

```
do{
    algo...
} while(el valor de id del cual quiero me traiga la información)
```

Pero **no funciona**, me debería traer el "titulo" y "autor" del registro 4 pero me sigue trayendo los del registro 1.

No sé si lo pensé bien pero es la manera que se me ocurrió. Entonces, como podría traerme la información de los 10 registros y llamar al que yo quiera, en vez de que solo me traiga el id = 1?

**EDITADO**

```
public class Libros implements Serializable {

private String id, titulo, autor, sinopsis, fechadepublicacion, editorial, cantidaddepaginas, idioma, categorias;

public Libros (String id, String titulo, String autor, String sinopsis, String fechadepublicacion, String editorial, String cantidaddepaginas, String idioma, String categorias){
    this.id = id;
    this.titulo = titulo;
    this.autor = autor;
    this.sinopsis = sinopsis;
    this.fechadepublicacion = fechadepublicacion;
    this.editorial = editorial;
    this.cantidaddepaginas = cantidaddepaginas;
    this.idioma = idioma;
    this.categorias = categorias;
}

public Libros(){
}

public String getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(String id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getTitulo() {
    return titulo;
}

public void setTitulo(String titulo) {
    this.titulo = titulo;
}

public String getAutor() {
    return autor;
}

public void setAutor(String autor) {
    this.autor = autor;
}

public String getSinopsis() {
    return sinopsis;
}

public void setSinopsis(String sinopsis) {
    this.sinopsis = sinopsis;
}

public String getFechadepublicacion() {
    return fechadepublicacion;
}

public void setFechadepublicacion(String fechadepublicacion) { this.fechadepublicacion = fechadepublicacion; }

public String getEditorial() {
    return editorial;
}

public void setEditorial(String editorial) {
    this.editorial = editorial;
}

public String getCantidaddepaginas() {
    return cantidaddepaginas;
}

public void setCantidaddepaginas(String cantidaddepaginas) { this.cantidaddepaginas = cantidaddepaginas; }

public String getIdioma() {
    return idioma;
}

public void setIdioma(String idioma) {
    this.idioma = idioma;
}

public String getCategorias() {
    return categorias;
}

public void setCategorias(String categorias) {
    this.categorias = categorias;
}
}
```

**EDITADO 2 - Agrego la clase BaseDeDatos**

```
public class BaseDeDatos extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

public BaseDeDatos(Context context) {
    super(context, "libros.db", null, 1);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS libros (Id text, Titulo text, Autor text, Sinopsis text, FechaDePublicacion text, Editorial text, CantidadDePaginas text, Idioma text, Categorias text)");
    db.execSQL("insert into libros values" +
            "('1', 'El Resplandor', 'Stephen King', '¿Qué ha sido de Danny Torrance? Descúbrelo al final de este volumen, que incluye el inicio de Doctor Sueño, la continuación de El resplandor. REDRUM. Esa es la palabra que Danny había visto en el espejo. Y, aunque no sabía leer, entendió que era un mensaje de horror. Tenía cinco años, y a esa edad pocos niños son conscientes de que los espejos invierten las imágenes, y menos aún diferencian entre realidad y fantasía. Pero Danny tenía pruebas de que sus fantasías relacionadas con el resplandor del espejo acabarían cumpliéndose: REDRUM... MURDER, asesinato. Su madre estaba pensando en el divorcio, y su padre, obsesionado con algo muy malo, tan malo como la muerte y el suicidio, necesitaba aceptar la propuesta de cuidar de aquel hotel de lujo, de más de cien habitaciones aislado por la nieve, durante seis meses. Hasta el deshielo iban a estar solos. ¿Solos?...', '28-01-1977', 'Doubleday', '447', 'Ingles', 'Terror')" +
            "('2', 'Forbidden', 'Tabitha Suzuma', 'No podemos. Si empezamos, ¿cómo vamos a pararlo? Lochan y Maya siempre se han sentido más amigos que hermanos. Ante la incapacidad de cuidarlos de su madre alcohólica y la ausencia de un padre que los abandonó, los dos jóvenes deben hacerse cargo de sus tres hermanos menores y esconder su situación a los servicios sociales, porque ninguno de los dos es mayor de edad. La responsabilidad que comparten y las dificultades a las que se enfrentan les unen, hasta empujarlos a enamorarse. Ambos saben que su relación está mal y que no debe continuar, pero al mismo tiempo no pueden controlar sus emociones y la atracción que los domina.', '10-05-2010', 'OZ', '387', 'Español', 'Ficción') " +
            "('3', 'Cazadores de Sombras', 'Harald Zwart', 'En la ciudad de Nueva York, una adolescente aparentemente común llamada Clary Fray descubre que ella desciende de una línea de guerreros, mitad ángeles, quienes protegen a la humanidad de los demonios. Después de que su madre desaparece, Clary une fuerzas con un grupo de cazadores de sombras e ingresa al Inframundo, un sitio peligroso y alterno lleno de demonios, brujos, vampiros, hombres lobo y criaturas sobrenaturales.', '22-07-2013', 'Simon & Schuster', '948', 'Español', 'Ficción') " +
            "('4', 'Beautiful Disaster', 'Jamie McGuire', 'La chica buena Abby no bebe, no se mete en líos y trabaja muy duro. Cree que ha enterrado su oscuro pasado, pero cuando llega a la universidad, un rompecorazones conocido por sis ligues de una noche pone en peligro su sueño de una nueva vida. El chico malo Travis Maddox , sexy, musculoso y cubierto de tatuajes, es justamente el tipo de chico que le atrae a Abby, justamente lo que quiere evitar. Dedica sus noches a ganar dinero en un club de lucha itinerante y sus dias a ser el estudiante ejemplar y el seductor mas popular del campus. Toda una mezcla explosiva. Intrigado por el rechazo de Abby, Travis intenta colarse en su vida proponiendole una apuesta que trastocará sus mundos y lo cambiará todo.', '26-05-2011', 'Simon & Schuster', '567', 'Ingles', 'Romance') " +
            "('5', 'Hush Hush', 'Becca Fitzpatrick', 'Cuando Patch se convierte en su nuevo compañero de laboratorio de biología, Nora siente a la vez atracción y repulsión hacia este extraño personaje que parece tener acceso a sus pensamientos. Luego se entera de que Patch es un ángel caído que quiere convertirse en humano.', '13-10-2009', 'Ediciones B', '647', 'Ingles', 'Romance') " +
            "('6', 'Los juegos del hambre', 'Collins Suzanne', 'En lo que alguna vez fue Norteamérica, la Capital de Panem mantiene sus 12 distritos obligándolos a seleccionar a un niño y a una niña, llamados Tributos, a competir en un evento televisado nacionalmente llamados Juegos del Hambre. Cada ciudadano debe ver pelear a muerte a los jóvenes. El Trbuto del Distrito 12, Katniss Everdeen sólo confía en sus habilidades de caza y buenos instintos en una arena en donde debe sobrevivir contra la humanidad.', '14-09-2008', 'Rba-Molino', '847', 'Español', 'Fantasía') " +
            "('7', 'Misery', 'Stephen King', 'Un autor se recupera de un accidente y es cuidado por una admiradora que le insiste escribir un libro sólo para ella.', '08-06-1987', 'Viking Press', '320', 'Ingles', 'Terror') " +
            "('8', 'Oscuros', 'Kate Lauren', 'La historia de Daniel y Luce, dos almas predestinadas a encontrarse y condenadas a perderse... Helstone, Inglaterra, 1854. Es noche cerrada y dos jóvenes conversan en una remota casa de campo. Se sienten irresistiblemente atraídos el uno por el otro, pero él insiste en que no pueden estar juntos.', '08-12-2009', 'Penguin Random House', '416', 'Ingles', 'Drama') " +
            "('9', 'Eleanor & Park', 'Rowell Rainbow', 'Dos chicos de un colegio, que se conocen por una situación fortuita en el autobús escolar, haciendo que de poco a poco su amistad vaya evolucionando en algo más. Pero no todo en la vida es fácil, al final, los dos protagonistas tendrán que luchar por mantenerse juntos, he impedir que el padrastro de Eleanor los separen para siempre.', '07-10-2012', 'Aguilar', '333', 'Ingles', 'Romance') " +
            "('10', 'El amante japonés', 'Isabel Allende', 'La historia de amor entre la joven Alma Belasco y el jardinero japonés Ichimei conduce al lector por un recorrido a través de diversos escenarios que van desde la Polonia de la Segunda Guerra Mundial hasta el San Francisco de nuestros días «A los veintidós años, sospechando que tenían el tiempo contado, Ichimei y Alma se atragantaron de amor para consumirlo entero, pero mientras más intentaban agotarlo, más imprudente era el deseo, y quien diga que todo fuego se apaga solo tarde o temprano, se equivoca: hay pasiones que son incendios hasta que las ahoga el destino de un zarpazo y aun así quedan brasas calientes listas para arder apenas se les da oxígeno.', '22-05-2015', 'Plaza & Janés', '725', 'Español', 'Drama') ");
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS libros");
    db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS libros (Id text, Titulo text, Autor text, Sinopsis text, FechaDePublicacion text, Editorial text, CantidadDePaginas text, Idioma text, Categorias text)");
    db.execSQL("insert into libros values" +
            "('1', 'El Resplandor', 'Stephen King', '¿Qué ha sido de Danny Torrance? Descúbrelo al final de este volumen, que incluye el inicio de Doctor Sueño, la continuación de El resplandor. REDRUM. Esa es la palabra que Danny había visto en el espejo. Y, aunque no sabía leer, entendió que era un mensaje de horror. Tenía cinco años, y a esa edad pocos niños son conscientes de que los espejos invierten las imágenes, y menos aún diferencian entre realidad y fantasía. Pero Danny tenía pruebas de que sus fantasías relacionadas con el resplandor del espejo acabarían cumpliéndose: REDRUM... MURDER, asesinato. Su madre estaba pensando en el divorcio, y su padre, obsesionado con algo muy malo, tan malo como la muerte y el suicidio, necesitaba aceptar la propuesta de cuidar de aquel hotel de lujo, de más de cien habitaciones aislado por la nieve, durante seis meses. Hasta el deshielo iban a estar solos. ¿Solos?...', '28-01-1977', 'Doubleday', '447', 'Ingles', 'Terror')" +
            "('2', 'Forbidden', 'Tabitha Suzuma', 'No podemos. Si empezamos, ¿cómo vamos a pararlo? Lochan y Maya siempre se han sentido más amigos que hermanos. Ante la incapacidad de cuidarlos de su madre alcohólica y la ausencia de un padre que los abandonó, los dos jóvenes deben hacerse cargo de sus tres hermanos menores y esconder su situación a los servicios sociales, porque ninguno de los dos es mayor de edad. La responsabilidad que comparten y las dificultades a las que se enfrentan les unen, hasta empujarlos a enamorarse. Ambos saben que su relación está mal y que no debe continuar, pero al mismo tiempo no pueden controlar sus emociones y la atracción que los domina.', '10-05-2010', 'OZ', '387', 'Español', 'Ficción') " +
            "('3', 'Cazadores de Sombras', 'Harald Zwart', 'En la ciudad de Nueva York, una adolescente aparentemente común llamada Clary Fray descubre que ella desciende de una línea de guerreros, mitad ángeles, quienes protegen a la humanidad de los demonios. Después de que su madre desaparece, Clary une fuerzas con un grupo de cazadores de sombras e ingresa al Inframundo, un sitio peligroso y alterno lleno de demonios, brujos, vampiros, hombres lobo y criaturas sobrenaturales.', '22-07-2013', 'Simon & Schuster', '948', 'Español', 'Ficción') " +
            "('4', 'Beautiful Disaster', 'Jamie McGuire', 'La chica buena Abby no bebe, no se mete en líos y trabaja muy duro. Cree que ha enterrado su oscuro pasado, pero cuando llega a la universidad, un rompecorazones conocido por sis ligues de una noche pone en peligro su sueño de una nueva vida. El chico malo Travis Maddox , sexy, musculoso y cubierto de tatuajes, es justamente el tipo de chico que le atrae a Abby, justamente lo que quiere evitar. Dedica sus noches a ganar dinero en un club de lucha itinerante y sus dias a ser el estudiante ejemplar y el seductor mas popular del campus. Toda una mezcla explosiva. Intrigado por el rechazo de Abby, Travis intenta colarse en su vida proponiendole una apuesta que trastocará sus mundos y lo cambiará todo.', '26-05-2011', 'Simon & Schuster', '567', 'Ingles', 'Romance') " +
            "('5', 'Hush Hush', 'Becca Fitzpatrick', 'Cuando Patch se convierte en su nuevo compañero de laboratorio de biología, Nora siente a la vez atracción y repulsión hacia este extraño personaje que parece tener acceso a sus pensamientos. Luego se entera de que Patch es un ángel caído que quiere convertirse en humano.', '13-10-2009', 'Ediciones B', '647', 'Ingles', 'Romance') " +
            "('6', 'Los juegos del hambre', 'Collins Suzanne', 'En lo que alguna vez fue Norteamérica, la Capital de Panem mantiene sus 12 distritos obligándolos a seleccionar a un niño y a una niña, llamados Tributos, a competir en un evento televisado nacionalmente llamados Juegos del Hambre. Cada ciudadano debe ver pelear a muerte a los jóvenes. El Trbuto del Distrito 12, Katniss Everdeen sólo confía en sus habilidades de caza y buenos instintos en una arena en donde debe sobrevivir contra la humanidad.', '14-09-2008', 'Rba-Molino', '847', 'Español', 'Fantasía') " +
            "('7', 'Misery', 'Stephen King', 'Un autor se recupera de un accidente y es cuidado por una admiradora que le insiste escribir un libro sólo para ella.', '08-06-1987', 'Viking Press', '320', 'Ingles', 'Terror') " +
            "('8', 'Oscuros', 'Kate Lauren', 'La historia de Daniel y Luce, dos almas predestinadas a encontrarse y condenadas a perderse... Helstone, Inglaterra, 1854. Es noche cerrada y dos jóvenes conversan en una remota casa de campo. Se sienten irresistiblemente atraídos el uno por el otro, pero él insiste en que no pueden estar juntos.', '08-12-2009', 'Penguin Random House', '416', 'Ingles', 'Drama') " +
            "('9', 'Eleanor & Park', 'Rowell Rainbow', 'Dos chicos de un colegio, que se conocen por una situación fortuita en el autobús escolar, haciendo que de poco a poco su amistad vaya evolucionando en algo más. Pero no todo en la vida es fácil, al final, los dos protagonistas tendrán que luchar por mantenerse juntos, he impedir que el padrastro de Eleanor los separen para siempre.', '07-10-2012', 'Aguilar', '333', 'Ingles', 'Romance') " +
            "('10', 'El amante japonés', 'Isabel Allende', 'La historia de amor entre la joven Alma Belasco y el jardinero japonés Ichimei conduce al lector por un recorrido a través de diversos escenarios que van desde la Polonia de la Segunda Guerra Mundial hasta el San Francisco de nuestros días «A los veintidós años, sospechando que tenían el tiempo contado, Ichimei y Alma se atragantaron de amor para consumirlo entero, pero mientras más intentaban agotarlo, más imprudente era el deseo, y quien diga que todo fuego se apaga solo tarde o temprano, se equivoca: hay pasiones que son incendios hasta que las ahoga el destino de un zarpazo y aun así quedan brasas calientes listas para arder apenas se les da oxígeno.', '22-05-2015', 'Plaza & Janés', '725', 'Español', 'Drama') ");
}
}
```

**EDITADO - Pruebo la respuesta de Jorge**

```
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long id) {
    BaseDeDatos admin = new BaseDeDatos(this);
    SQLiteDatabase db = admin.getWritableDatabase();
    Libros catego = null;
    listaLibros = new ArrayList<>();
    cursor = db.rawQuery("select * from libros" , null);
    while (cursor.moveToNext()){
        catego = new Libros();
        catego.setId(cursor.getString(0));
        catego.setTitulo(cursor.getString(1));
        catego.setAutor(cursor.getString(2));
        listaLibros.add(catego);
        }

        String info = (String) adapterView.getItemAtPosition(position);
     for (Libros libro : listaLibros){
            if (position == 0 && libro.getId() == "1") {
                Intent terror = new Intent(Terror.this, DatosLibro.class);
                terror.putExtra("titulo", titulo);
                terror.putExtra("autor", autor);
                startActivity(terror);
                break;
            }
        }
```

Comment: Hola Rodrigo, ¿"Traer" te refieres a que envíe los datos mediante el intent hacia DatosLibro ?

Comment: hola Jorge, claro me refiero a eso, quiero enviar los datos hacia DatosLibro, pero según el registro que yo necesite, es decir la informacion de id=2 o id=4 y asi con los 10

Comment: OK imagino que tu objeto tiene getters y setters para agregar el valor de titulo y autor verdad ?@Rodrigo

Comment: OK imagino que tu objeto tiene getters y setters para agregar el valor de titulo y autor verdad @Rodrigo

Comment: si, tiene getters y setters!

Comment: @Jorgesys sabes cómo puedo hacer?

Comment: Agrego respuesta! revisa @Rodrigo

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/87345/discussion-between-rodrigo-and-jorgesys).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Primeramente agrega los valores de titulo y autor obtenidos en el cursor a tu objeto "catego":

```
while (cursor.moveToNext()){
    catego = new Libros();
    catego.setId(cursor.getString(0));

    //Agrega titulo y autor
    catego.setTitulo(cursor.getString(1));
    catego.setAutor(cursor.getString(2));

    listaLibros.add(catego);
    cat = Integer.parseInt(catego.getId());
    }
```

de esta forma tendrías la información necesaria de todos los elementos en el ArrayList `listaLibros`.

Posterior a esto simplemente revisa  los elementos y si el id coincide, se realizará el intent sin problema

```
for(Libros libro : listaLibros){

 if(libro.getId().equals("4")){ 

    Intent terror = new Intent(Terror.this, DatosLibro.class);
    terror.putExtra("titulo", libro.getTitulo());
    terror.putExtra("autor", libro.getAutor());
    startActivity(terror);

    //termina el for
    break;
 }

}
```

---

Si deseas usar la variable position para abrir el registro correspond

```
   ...
   ...
   int idElemento = position +1;

    for(Libros libro : listaLibros){

     if(libro.getId().equals(String.valueOf(idElemento))){ 

        Intent terror = new Intent(Terror.this, DatosLibro.class);
        terror.putExtra("titulo", libro.getTitulo());
        terror.putExtra("autor", libro.getAutor());
        startActivity(terror);

        //termina el for
        break;
     }

    }
    ...
    ...
```

Comment: lo he intentado como dices, y no me genera ningún tipo de error pero cuando toco en el elemento de la lista para que me lleve a DatosLibro (y verificar si funcionó o no) no hace nada, como si el elemento no tuviera ningún evento. Te edito el post agregando al final el código para mostrarte como quedó.

Comment: recuerda que la comparación de Strings se realiza mediante .equals( ) @Rodrigo  debería ser:   if (position == 0 && libro.getId().equals("1")) , revisa mi respuesta

Comment: cierto, corregido mediante el .equals(), ahora pasa algo muy curioso. Si en el .equals() tengo "1" si me lleva a DatosLibros y me muestra el titulo y autor del primer registro (id=1), pero si en el .equals() pongo cualquier otro valor, "2", "3", etc, de vuelta no pasa nada al clickear el elemento. Me resulta muy raro, no sabés que podrá ser?

Comment: No creo que sea necesario validar "position" aquí:   if (position == 0 && libro.getId().equals("1")) { , ¿Alguna razón? me parece que solo el elemento con id a abrir sería suficiente:  if (libro.getId().equals("2")) { @Rodrigo

Comment: si @Jorgesys, la razón es porque en este caso tengo 2 elementos (positions), entonces quiero que cuando toque el elemento 1 (position == 0), me mande a DatosLibros con la informacion del id=1 y si toco el elemento 2 (position == 1), lo mismo pero con la informacion del id=2.

Comment: @Rodrigo bueno esta pregunta también ya estaba solucionada solo que el problema era algo relacionado a la DB

Comment: si, lo brindado por @Jorgesys funciona a la perfección, era un problema con la creación de los registros en mi BD